# DPC around a window (UK)

Tags: garage, damp-proof-course

I had an integrated garage in the house. I have recently had a builder come and replace the garage door with a brick wall and a large bay window as I plan to turn this garage into an office.
I have contacted building control at our local council and they have rejected the application because there is no Damp Proof Course around the brick pillar.

See picture[image: GarageWindow]

The building controller, who I contact over whatsapp doesn't respond to my questions. The builder has gone AWOL and I'm not sure what to do.

The one thing I did get from building control was:

*I would have wrapped the internal   face of the piers in DPM, before plasterboarding*

Does he mean all I have to do is put a Damp Proof Membrane around the pillar from the window to the blocks?

I wish he would just respond but he takes days to come back to me and I want to proceed with the job.

Will I end up having to remove the window, fit a Damp Proof Course, and then put it back again?

This is in the UK.

Comment: I should have mentioned this is in the UK.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], Mark. Please feel free to [edit] your location into your question. It will help ensure others can easily find it because many people don't read the comments, only the question. Also, while you're waiting for an answer, please take the [tour] and read through the [help] so you know what to expect and can make the most of this site. One additional thought, while you're [edit]ing your post, it might be helpful to include a picture of the outside of the new window & wall.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to help, but I'm curious; what's DPC and DPM? (Edit the answer into your question. Thanks.)

Comment: I've added DPC and DPM - thanks @DanielGriscom

Answer (score 1):

Where a cavity wall meets an opening like a window or door like in this case the regs state that's necessary to fit a DPC that prevents moisture from entering the cavity and also prevents cold spots forming on the internal wall

A vertical DPC is also often installed where 2 separate walls meet for moisture proofing so that would need to be clarified which area they are requiring the DPC possibly both

I assume that is what the inspector is talking about; it is likely in the first case you will have to refit the window the builder should of informed you about this before putting it in